# Page Reloading after data update using AJAX & also ALERT not showing after data update

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to update some data in using PHP & AJAX but my alert is not showing. In function(response) i am getting "success" message from PHP file. Please advise

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
<body>
  <div style="margin: auto;width: 60%;">
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id="success" style="display:none;">
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
</div>
```

---------- MY AJAX SCRIPT ----------

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".upr").click(function(){
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        var request=$form.find('[name="request"]').data("request");
        var userid=$form.find('[name="userid"]').data("userid");
        var pr=$form.find('[id="pr"]').val()
        
        //alert(+pr+"/"+userid+"/"+request);
            $.ajax({
            url:'update.php',
            method:'POST',
            data:{
                request:request,
                userid:userid,
                pr:pr
                
                },
                success:function(response){
                 //alert(response);
                 $("#success").show();
                $('#success').html(response);
                
                }
            });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check `Network` tab in your browser and ensure you have 200+ HTTP code when AJAX produced, otherwise you won't reach `success` callback. Also, you can add `error` callback and do some `console.log`. This might give you some clue what is happening:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'update.php',
    method:'POST',
    data:{
        request:request,
        userid:userid,
        pr:pr

    },
    success:function(response){
        //alert(response);
        $("#success").show();
        $('#success').html(response);

    },
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Error happened', jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks! I tested it & getting 200 in Network tab. I am getting SUCCESS response from php file, however my alert is not coming up with "SUCCESS" message

Comment: if you do `console.log(response)` inside `success` callback, do you see any response? And also, do you return anything from `update.php`? Is it JSON response or some HTML?

Comment: i did got ECHO output back in success:function(response), Only issue is with alert

Comment: Let's check a few other things. Check that you have only one ID `success` on the page, also try to run `$('#success')` in the console. What DOM elements do you see? Do you see one you expect to be shown? If you get one you want, try manually executing part of success callback in your console and see if it works for you.

Comment: Hi Alex, its resolved. Thanks!! The issue for reloading was because i didn't used preventDefault(); . Since it was reloading alerts were not showing. Now everything working as expected

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", '.upr', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        var req=$form.find('[name="request"]').data("req");
        var uid=$form.find('[name="userid"]').data("uid");
        var notes=$('#tab'+request).children('td[data-target=notes]').text();
        var pr=$form.find('[id="pr"]').val()

    
    $.ajax({
            url:'update.php',
            method:'POST',
            data:{
                req:req,
                uid:uid,
                pr:pr
                },
                success:function(response){

          var newHtml = 'C P = ' + pr;
             $('.proo'+request).html(newHtml);
                 alert(response);
                 
                },
                error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log('Error happened', jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                 }
            });
    
    })
});
```